# Check if output of a shell command is empty in Lua

Tags: bash, shell, lua, command, conditional-statements

I am trying to activate some Lua lines only if the output of `pgrep -x foo` is empty. I have tried the following:

```
if os.execute("pgrep -x foo") then
   -- My lines here
end
```

However, this doesn't seem to be the correct solution, even syntactically OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```lua
local result = os.execute("pgrep -x foo")
if result ~= true and result ~= 0 then
   -- My lines here (no such process)
end
```

Comment: @JoeC Something tells me Egor has been around for a while ;)

Comment: Could you explain why you're using two conditions, please? I think you're behind the right answer, but I'm not understanding the full part of it.

Comment: @xvlaze - `os.execute` returns different results for Lua [5.1](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-os.execute) and [5.2+](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-os.execute).  The condition `result ~= true and result ~= 0` works everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try checking for `nil`:

```
if os.execute('pgrep -x foo') == nil then
    print('empty')
end
```

If you don't want the match to be "exact" then remove the `-x` option.